# read_csv doesn't get accents correctly

Tags: r, csv, encoding, export-to-csv, readr

I'm reading a UTF-8 encoded file with `readr::read_csv("path_to/file.csv", locale = locale(encoding = "utf-8"))` but still doesn't get the spanish accents correctly.

I wrote the file with `readr::write_csv(file, "path_to/file.csv")` and the output of `readr::guess_encoding("path_to/file.csv")` is UTF-8 with 100% confidence.

As a side note, eveytime I wrote the file, the R session run into fatal error, but the file was still written.

What can I do to get strings with correct accents?

---

## EDIT

I've found [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/1314) in `readr`'s github repo, pointing out that the error should disappear with the latest `vroom` release, but in my case didn't.

Comment: What is the size of the data.frame/file? The fact that something "explodes" (can you be more specific?) hints that something may be going awry. Have you tried writing using `write.table`?

Comment: I meant that the R bomb appears. The file size is 2.2 MB.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what an R bomb is? If you're referring to a RStudio crash, you could try updating the version (perhaps a daily build?) or running the code through the console ("natively").

Comment: I just tried `write.csv` and doesn't kills the session, but `read_csv` still doesn't work as expected, neither does `read.csv`.

Comment: Running the code through the console results in the same output as running it through the r chunk in rmarkdown.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the accent marks issue: when calling my funs.R file, which contains all relevant functions on data preprocessing and was used before writting the csv, I wasn't doing it correctly. Apparently, file sourcing is done with R's defult encoding, which isn't necessarily the same encoding of the file itself. I just had to set `encoding = "utf-8"` argument into `source()`.

I wasn't able to resolve the fatal error.